# Using constants in SSRS's Error Bar Chart

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 report with a Error Bar chart.  It plots dates (x-axis) versus score (y-axis), with +10/-10 for the upper/lower error range.  But in the dataset, I also have two sets averages (the US and the company's).

I would like to display these averages as a constant.  It should be a horizontal line that runs through the chart.

In the chart, I have as category field: the date.  As datafields: the score, the US average score, and the company's average score.  Thus far I can plot all these points, but it seems that the averages' points are plotted simply as points, and are treated as points that should have upper/lower error ranges.

My question is, how can I get these averages to not display as points with ranges, but as a linear constant that is connected as a straight line?  It seems as though with the Error Bar chart, it only wants to plot points with ranges.

(I have screenshots of what I have and what I want, but my work is blocking any image hosting sites.  I will try to upload images later if this is still unclear.)

Thank-you in advance.

(Update)
Just to be clear, the two averages aren't calculated out, they exist as a column as part of the dataset retrieved.  So for each row, these values are always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that each series in the SSRS chart, you can change the chart type.  In my case, I had to change it to Line graph to get the constant to show as a horizontal line.

So although the chart itself is a Error bar chart, each of the series can be changed to whatever bar chart needed.

(It was my co-worker that discovered this property-- so props to him)